# Trie Autocomplete with word weight(frequency)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie

I was asked this during a recent phone interview -
Given a Dictionary with a word and the weight of a word(frequency, higher is better), like so -

```
            var words = new Dictionary<string,int>();
            words.Add("am",7);
            words.Add("ant", 5);
            words.Add("amazon", 10);
            words.Add("amazing", 8);
            words.Add("an", 4);
            words.Add("as", 11);
            words.Add("be", 8);
            words.Add("bee", 2);
            words.Add("bed", 4);
            words.Add("best", 12);
            words.Add("amuck", 1);
            words.Add("amock", 2);
            words.Add("bestest", 1);
```

Design an API method, that given a prefix and a number k, return the top k words that match the prefix.
The words should be sorted based on their weight, the higher the better.

- So, prefix = "am", k = 5, returns amazon, amazing, am, amock, amuck *- in that specific order.*
- Performance on the prefix lookup is paramount, you can pre-process and use as much space as you like, as long as the prefix lookup is fast.

This is a Trie implementation, but my question is how best to handle the word weight and optimise the lookup. In my mind the options are -

a. For each node in the Trie, also store a sorted list of words (`SortedDictionary<int,List<string>>`) that start with this prefix - more space, but faster lookup.

b. For each node, store the Child nodes in some kind of sorted list, so you would still need to do a DFS for each child node to get the K words needed - less space compared to a., but slower.

I decided to go with option a.

```
    public class TrieWithSuggestions
    {
        TrieWithSuggestions _trieRoot;
        public TrieWithSuggestions()
        {
        }

        public char Character { get; set; }
        public int WordCount { get; set; } = 1;
        public TrieWithSuggestions[] ChildNodes { get; set; } = new TrieWithSuggestions[26];
        //Stores all words with this prefix.
        public SortedDictionary<int, HashSet<string>> PrefixWordsDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();

        public TrieWithSuggestions ConstructTrie(Dictionary<string, int> words)
        {
            if (words.Count > 0)
            {
                _trieRoot = new TrieWithSuggestions() { Character = default(char) };
                foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    var node = _trieRoot;
                    for (int i = 0; i < word.Key.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var c = word.Key[i];
                        if (node.ChildNodes[c - 'a'] != null)
                        {
                            node = node.ChildNodes[c - 'a'];
                            UpdateParentNodeInformation(node, word.Key, words[word.Key]);
                            node.WordCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            InsertIntoTrie(node, word.Key, i, words);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return _trieRoot;
        }

        public List<string> GetMathchingWords(string prefix, int k)
        {
            if (_trieRoot != null)
            {
                var node = _trieRoot;
                foreach (var ch in prefix)
                {
                    if (node.ChildNodes[ch - 'a'] != null)
                    {
                        node = node.ChildNodes[ch - 'a'];
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                }

                if (node != null)
                    return GetWords(node, k);
                else
                    return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        List<string> GetWords(TrieWithSuggestions node, int k)
        {
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (var dictEntry in node.PrefixWordsDictionary)
            {
                var entries = node.PrefixWordsDictionary[dictEntry.Key];
                var take = Math.Min(entries.Count, k);
                output.AddRange(entries.Take(take).ToList());
                k -= entries.Count;
                if (k == 0)
                    break;
            }
            return output;
        }

        void InsertIntoTrie(TrieWithSuggestions parentNode, string word, int startIndex, Dictionary<string, int> words)
        {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                var c = word[i];
                var childNode = new TrieWithSuggestions() { Character = c };
                parentNode.ChildNodes[c - 'a'] = childNode;
                UpdateParentNodeInformation(parentNode, word, words[word]);
                parentNode = childNode;

                if (i == word.Length - 1)
                    UpdateParentNodeInformation(parentNode, word, words[word]);
            }
        }

        void UpdateParentNodeInformation(TrieWithSuggestions parentNode, string word, int wordWeight)
        {
            wordWeight *= -1;
            if (parentNode.PrefixWordsDictionary.ContainsKey(wordWeight))
            {
                if (!parentNode.PrefixWordsDictionary[wordWeight].Contains(word))
                    parentNode.PrefixWordsDictionary[wordWeight].Add(word);
            }
            else
                parentNode.PrefixWordsDictionary.Add(wordWeight, new HashSet<string>() { word });
        }
    }
```

`Construct Trie` - RunTime O(N* M * logN), Space - O(N * M * N) , N - #of words, M - avg word length.

Justification -
If there were no Dictionary, this would be O(N * M), insertion into a `SortedDictionary` is O(logN), so worst case Runtime must be O(N* M * logN)

Space seems trickier, but like before if there were no `SortedDictionary`, space would be O(N * M), and in the worst case, the Dictionary could have all N words, so Space Complexity looks like O(N * M * N)

`GetMatchingWords` - RunTime O(len(prefix) + k)

Function call -

```
            var trie = new TrieWithSuggestions();
            trie.ConstructTrie(words);
            var list = trie.GetMathchingWords("am", 10); //amazon, amazing, am, amock, amuck
```

QUESTION:
Given the conditions on space and pre-processing, is there a better way to do this?

EDIT 1 -

a. Given this setup, it is best to sort the words by weight and then insert into the `Trie`. In this case a simple `List<string>` would suffice, since higher frequency words would have been inserted first automatically.

b. Now lets say that in addition to being initialized with a `Dictionary<string,int>`, we are also going to get additional word, frequency pairs. We would still want a lookup that is as fast as possible, given this requirement what is now the best data-structure to store the sorted list of words within a TrieNode, is a `SortedDictionary<int,HashSet<string>>` the best option?

Answer (score 2):

You could first sort the input with respect to the weights. Then, you could use `Lists` instead of `Dictionaries` on the nodes of `trie`. Since the words come in increasing (or decreasing) order of weight, checking the last element of the list is enough to decide where to put this new word. This gets rid of the *O(logN)* time taken by `Dictionary`.

The input can be sorted in *O(N * logN)* with a comparison sort, or in *O(N + W)* with a counting sort where W is the maximum weight.

Time complexity of setting up the trie becomes *O(N * logN + N * M)*. This is better than *O(N * M * logN)*. Query time does not change.

*(Last paragraph assumes `HashSet` operations execute in *O(1)* as in the question. It is wrong to make this assumption for arbitrary inputs and hash functions.)*

Comment: Good point, that is the suggestion I made at the end, actually at the start the requirement was to sort on both the weight and then lexicographical, I simplified this in my question.

If the sort is indeed needed at two levels, I would wager that it is best to do the 2 sorts on the input as well - wouldn't you agree.
Also on the O(1) for hash functions, yes this is amortised O(1), I think that part was okay for the interviewer.

Comment: I totally agree. Since we could be inserting all the words at the first node of trie anyways, if we are expected to give a sorted result, sorting the input first and then constructing the trie makes so much sense. Also I feel like having the input sorted lexicographical may allow further improvement. For example, we don't need `HashSet`s anymore, we can instead hold start and end indices into the input array. This is again a minor optimization though.